# How to find windows process by process id on commandline

Tags: command-line, process, cmd, pid, tasklist

I have two processes running (foo.cmd and bar.cmd on Windows7 prof), which both check frequently if the other process is still running.
Since each process knows the PID of the other process in the variable `%FPID%`, I used to check if the other process is still running like this

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%a in ('tasklist /FI "PID eq %FPID%" /NH ^| find /C "%FPID%"') do set COUNTP=%%a
```

If `%COUNTP%` was now bigger than 0, the other process was still running.

But every now and then `%COUNTP%` was equals 0 even if the other process was actually still running (It still wrote into logfiles).
A second later it could be found again.

- Which circumstances could lead to not find a running process by its ID like I do with the statement above?
- Is there a better/nicer/faster way to check if a process for a certain PID is still active and running (on windows)?

Comment: can you explain how these batches know each other's pids, did you grep `WMIC PROCESS` earlier in the script ?  We'd have to replicate that in the WMI watcher for it to work like you want.    Or are you asking for help on how to do that and I should explain it ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get the PID of each process like here[http://serverfault.com/questions/126502] and write them to files (foo.dat and bar.dat). Now they can just read from the file and save the content into the variable `%FPID%` like `set /p FPID=<"C:\tmp\foo.dat"`. This works really well and usually I can identify the other running process by this ID every minute. just every ~250th time I can't find the other process - why could it be invisible to the command `tasklist /FI "PID eq %FPID%" /N`

Comment: The reason would likely be that the PID is wrong or the process was not running.  Maybe your watchdog process restarted it and is why it was then found.  We'd be guessing without seeing your code.

Comment: or maybe it couldn't set the new pid in the foo.dat file. This shows the correct pid on-the-fly from powershell, but can it be re-written for WMIC.  `(get-process | where {$_.mainwindowtitle -match "Foo"}|select ID).ID`

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I am looking at the __InstanceDeletionEvent class for a WMI event watcher.  If you choose that route, this snip will get you in the right direction, courtesy the WMI Code Creator.

Basically WMI will wait and detect when the $pid closes, and execute commands within 1 second of that happening.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance.ProcessId = 1900")

Wscript.Echo "Waiting for events ..."
Do While(True)
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent

    'report an event
    Wscript.Echo "__InstanceDeletionEvent event has occurred."

Loop
```